# Validation of the coloerd coin transaction

Tags: transactions

In Bitcoin, transactions are validated using UTXO.
How is the colored coin transaction (including Counterparty) validated?
For example, when balance of that user defined assets is zero, or when user are trying double spent, how does the validation activated?